# Using Async and Await in Ionic3 and angular4

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework, async-await

we never used await/async, so the question could be also a stupid one but what do we wrong?

This is our code:

```
  constructor() {
       let text = this.textAsync();
       console.log('text: ', text);
  }


  async textAsync() {
    let val = await this._text(); 
    return val;
  }

  _text(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           resolve('TEEEEXXTTTTT');
    })
  }
```

The log is never `text: TEEEEXXTTTTT` but something like that

```
text: ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array[0]}
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution :smile:

thx

Answer (score 0):

`this.textAsync();` returns a promise, so you have to wait until it's resolved:

```
  constructor() {
       this.textAsync()
       .then((text)=> { console.log('text: ', text) });
  }
```

Comment: But If I see this example
https://www.joshmorony.com/using-asyncawait-syntax-for-promises-in-ionic/ getFromStorageAsync is doing the same and he is not calling .then ...
I'm really confused :o, can you perhaps share a plnkr?

Comment: sure, here is [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E6yvgcgvN3tsAIkWlkjg?p=preview). `async functions` return a promise. You can skip using `then`, but in this case you will get a reference to the promise as you have in your case  `ZoneAwarePromise`, not the result of the promise resolution. Where in the article you mentioned he doesn't use then?

Comment: @MichaelBurger, hey, so did my answer help?